# Symfony 2 query builder join

Tags: symfony, formbuilder

I wrote this function in my Repository.php file:

**PermitsRepository**:

```
public function findPermits($permitId, $permitname, $permitsurname, $company, $contractor, $date) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('e');


        $query = $qb->where('e.Permitid like :permitid and e.Permitname like :permitname and e.Permitsurname like :permitsurname and c.name like:company and r.name like:contractor and e.expirationdate like :date')
            ->setParameter('permitid','%'.$permitId.'%')
            ->setParameter('permitname','%'.$permitname.'%')
            ->setParameter('permitsurname','%'.$permitsurname.'%')
            ->setParameter('company','%'.$company.'%')
            ->setParameter('contractor','%'.$contractor.'%')
            ->setParameter('date','%'.$date.'%')
            ->join('e.PermitsCompany', 'c')
            ->join('e.PermitsContractor', 'r');



        $query->orderBy('e.id', 'DESC');



        return $query->getQuery();
    }
```

And the point is that I want to join two tables. *Company* and *Contractor*,
and this *PermitsCompany* and *PermitsContractor* are connections bettwen table *Permits* and *Company* and *Contractor*.

In query I want to get row with NAME from table Company and Contractor.

```
c.name like:company 
and r.name like:contractor
```

**But i get an error:**

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 228: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'like:company'
```

Comment: you're missing spaces between `like` and `:` - `like:company` should be `like :company`

Comment: If you want to actually load company and contractor in the same query then add $qb->select('e','c','r'); otherwise company and contractor will be lazy loaded when accessed.  By the way, using one letter aliases is considered to be a crime against humanity.  Help stamp out this evil practice by using aliases such as company or contractor.  It's amazing how much easier it is to understand the query when you come back to it after a few months.